# How to get ImageView left-aligned with java coding?

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I have searched the solution about ImageView alignment. But most of the solutions are using layout.xml. To make it flexible, I'm using java code to add ImageView to layout. Following is my code. It always shows in the center. I need it go to the left.

```
        String uri="/xxx/xxx.png";
        File f = new File(uri);
        ImageView iv=new ImageView(cntxt);
        if (f.exists()) 
            iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uri));
        else
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.missing);
        iv.setMaxWidth(400);
        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p22 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        p22.gravity=Gravity.LEFT;
        linenearlayout.addView(iv, p22);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);` instead?

Comment: I finally resolved it. The solution is adding RelativeLayout to wrap ImageView. FYI.

Comment: For those who also need it: LinearLayout.LayoutParams p22 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p20 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        RelativeLayout rl=new RelativeLayout(cntxt);
        rl.addView(iv, p20);

Comment: I know you have already solved it but here's a suggestion. Instead of using the relative layout. Set your imageview's layout params as WRAP_CONTENT for both width and height. Should do the trick. Then you wouldnt need the additional relativelayout.

Comment: Hi, Shubhayu. I tried your solution. It's great! Thanks!